# Pulling specific filetypes from local directory to s3 bucket

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to pull all .xslx files in my local directory into my S3 bucket, but I'm struggling on how best to direct my script to locate and pull all files with that file extension.

Here is what I currently have, any directions/suggestions are appreciated.

```
def initialize(bucket:, object_key:, input_file_path:)
      @bucket = bucket
      @object_key = object_key
      @input_file_path = input_file_path
    end

    def call
      object = s3_resource.bucket(bucket).object(object_key)
      object.upload_file(input_file_path)
    end

    private

    attr_reader :bucket, :object_key, :input_file_path
```

Comment: Hi, you should have a more objective question. However, you can list files with a specific file type with `Dir.glob("*.xslx")`. Then you can iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the call when the input_file_path does not match:

```rb
def call
  return unless input_file_path.end_with?('.xslx')

  object = s3_resource.bucket(bucket).object(object_key)
  object.upload_file(input_file_path)
end
```